# Entity Framework sum time grouped by a date

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code and I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'long'

The error is coming from `(i => i.TotalHours)`.

What am I doing wrong? Or what do I have to change?

**Table**

[image: Entity Framework Table]

**ViewModel**

```
private void CalculateTime()
{
    var result = context.TimeSheets.GroupBy(o => o.StartDate)
                        .Select(g => new { StartDate = g.Key, total = g.Sum(i => i.TotalHours) });

    foreach (var group in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StartDate = {0} TotalHours={1}", group.StartDate, group.total);
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class TimeSheet
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string MachineID { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    [StringLength(225)]
    public string WorkDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(225)]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(225)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string TotalHours { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: On which line you are getting this error? Can you post the class that is involved in grouping?

Comment: Having two DateTime properties for separate date & time doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You are right, but actually combine date and time are not solving the problem, so i will take a closer look later at this topic

Comment: Storing `TotalHours` as string doesn't make much sense either. You better change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error I believe you need either to change your `TotalHours` type to `long` or to make a type conversion, try:
`(long)Convert.ToDouble(i.TotalHours)`

```
var result = context.TimeSheets.GroupBy(o => o.StartDate)
                    .Select(g => new { StartDate = g.Key, total = g.Sum(i => (long)Convert.ToDouble(i.TotalHours)) });
```